# Populating array with integers

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I want to populate NSarray with 50 integers. We know that NSarray accept only  objects. So I have to do 50 times

```
NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInit:10];
NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInit:212];
......
NSNumber *num50 = [NSNumber numberWithInit:12];
```

Is there more elegant way to achieve that, beacause looks stupid 50 lines of code only for create number objects ?

Comment: are all those integers hard-coded? I mean't what is the reason you need to type in 50 integers?

Comment: Are the integers chosen randomly ? Or do you have a fixed list ? I'm sure you can use a loop either way.

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray, lets say they are fixed list.

Comment: You can follow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469886/nsarray-of-int . May be u can find ur way...

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot use an array to store these numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:50 ];

    for (int i=0; i<0; i++) {
        NSNumber *number=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i];
        [array addObject:number];
        [number release];
    }
//do anything with arrray and release the array later.
```

is this OK or you are seeking anything else.?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `NSMutableArray`?

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<50; i++) {
    NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]; // use i or random numbers
    [arr addObject:num];
}
```

Comment: No, the code is correct. There's no need to release `num` since it is an autoreleased object.

Comment: num is not allocated, it's created using convenience construtor, so it shouldn't be released

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers do not seem to follow any particular pattern, so you might be better doing this by creating a C array first:

```
int myValues[] = { 10, 212, ..., 12 };
NSUInteger count = sizeof(myValues)/sizeof(int); // number of integers in myValues

// abstract the following into a function/method/category if doing more than once
NSMutableArray *objcValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
for(NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
   [objcValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myValues[ix]];
```