# how to convert NSMutable array with NSNumber into strings

Tags: iphone, ios

my array is containing ids they are in NSNumber how can i convert them in string my array is like below

```
1494447926,
1537064431,
1545735176,
1574825141,
1604834983,
1829486110,
1838260338,
1846543841,
1850381039,
100000039842949,
100000077723868,
100000103091995,
100000126558358,
100000130915431,
100000139092102,
100000157330187,
100000157646688,
100000197141710,
100000243178639,
100000249947961,
```

please give me sample code to convert it to string

Comment: string means int i = 10 and you want to get output like "TEN"?

Comment: How did you store integers into an array. You can only store integers as NSNumber.

Comment: please post in which way you want to get output ?

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469886/nsarray-of-int

Comment: do you want each integer value in one long string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all array can not store integer. It must be in NSNumber or it is in NSString itself.

In either of the case you can create a long string by appending them,

```
NSString *string=[yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Or, if you want each value as string then you need to create that much string and then access them.

```
 NSArray *numbersToStrings=[NSArray new];
 for(id element in yourArray){
     [numbersToStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",element];
 }
```

Here `numbersToStrings` contains all the values as string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
         NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++){
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
[newArr addObject:str];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d",1494447926];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only Search on Google** - `convert int to NSString` , multiple Answer are displayed 
by the way, your need to use only `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",YourIntValue]`

```
for (int i=0; i < MyArray.count; i++)
{
     NSString * String =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [MyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     NSLog(@"%@",String);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringWithFormat`

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [YourArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store integers into an array. If you are getting this response from server each would be NSNumber. You can type cast that to NSString.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
NSArray *ll=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
NSString *strinList=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ll objectAtIndex:0]];
```

try this ,if you required other help ,i am here .

Comment: @PrakashDesai Accept answer which solved your issue, as this helps others to refer

Comment: yeah i have accepted already