# add double array to nsmutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, double

I need to add a double array (as in double example[number of capacity];) to a nsmutablearray, but it seems it's harder than I thought. So I have:

```
NSMutableArray *sample; 
double ex[2];
```

as a global variable in my .m file

and in void method with two double paramaters which are example1 and example2 I am trying to

```
ex[0] = example1;
ex[1] = example2;
```

then add this ex array to nsmutablearray, however, I am getting error if I do this:

```
[sample addObject:ex];
```

somebody please help, I am also a newbie to this so I don't have much idea how. Thanks in advance!

I feel like I am not explaining myself that clear so I'll add this.

```
So basically, I want my mutablearray to look like this:

[[3.78,2.00], [4.6,8.90098], [67.9099, 56.788] ...]

like that
```

Comment: Not sure but this is possibly a duplicate - please check this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5469886/558933 . Does your `ex` array have to be a C array or can it be an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: it is a double array :)

Comment: `{ }` denotes a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: oh.. I see! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Objective-C objects can be added to `NSMutableArray`. Since an array of `double`s is *not* an Objective-C object, you need to wrap your array into something that can be placed in an Objective-C collection. For example, you can wrap it in `NSData`:

```
NSData *wrapped = [NSData dataWithBytes:ex, length:sizeof(ex)];
[sample addObject:wrapped];
```

Of course now you need to "unwrap" your array before accessing it:

```
NSData *wrapped = [sample objectAtIndex:...];
double* tmp = (double*)wrapped.bytes;
double x = tmp[0];
```

Comment: that worked! But when I try to nslog the sample nsmutablearray the double value is not appearing anymore and is something like this <00000000 00506c40 00000000 00487e40>

Comment: @jane This is because `NSData` does not know what's inside, so it prints raw bytes. If you retrieve the data by unwrapping, you would get your `double` values back.

Comment: Oh no.. :( I am trying this code double* tmp = (double*)wrapped.data; but I'm getting an error "Property 'data' not found on object of type'NSData *' " I feel so stupid right now, I'm going to try what Metabble suggested, but thank you very much for the effort dasblinkenlight! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @jane Sorry, the property is called `bytes`, not `data`.

Comment: oh I see! Thanks a lot dasblinkenlight :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to Dasblinkenlight's answer, you could also use an NSArray of NSNumbers and add that to your NSMutableArray.

---

```
double example1 = 1.113;
double example2 = 129.74;
NSMutableArray *sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *ex = @[[NSNumber numberWithDouble: example1], [NSNumber numberWithDouble: example2]];
[sample addObject: ex];
NSLog(@"example1: %f, example2: %f", ((NSNumber*)sample[0][0]).doubleValue, ((NSNumber*)sample[0][1]).doubleValue);
//logs example1: 1.113000, example2: 129.740000
```

You can add as many NSArrays of NSNumber as you want and use `sample[][]` to get the NSNumber and then easily unwrap it with `doubleValue`.

If you want both dimensions to be mutable, simply put the NSNumbers in mutable arrays instead.

Change this:

```
NSArray *ex = @[[NSNumber numberWithDouble: example1], [NSNumber numberWithDouble: example2]];
```

to this:

```
NSMutableArray* ex = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: example1], [NSNumber numberWithDouble: example2], nil];
```

Comment: so the sample [] [] is a 2D  nsmutablearray? Interesting.. I'd try this :) thanks Metabble :)

Comment: sample would be a mutable array containing non-mutable arrays. So it's mutable in one dimension only. However, this is easily changed. I'll update the post.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot Metabble :)